# Show values that fail the query

Tags: php, mysql

This is a basic query that finds the condition of $sql.

```
$sql = "SELECT jobs.pickup as myPickup, jobs.dropoff as myDropoff FROM jobs, locality WHERE 
locality.pickup=jobs.pickup AND locality.dropOff=jobs.dropoff";
$test= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test)) {
echo "Pick up: " . $row["myPickup"]. " to ".$row["myDropoff"]."<br>";
```

How would you go about showing all the values that failed. I've tried

```
$row != mysqli_fetch_assoc($test)
//and
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) == false)
```

but don't seem to be getting anywhere. I also tried editing the SQL by this code:

```
SELECT jobs.pickup as myPickup, jobs.dropoff as myDropoff FROM jobs, locality WHERE locality.pickup!=jobs.pickup AND locality.dropOff!=jobs.dropoff
```

but  that didnt wor either and for some reason the SQL for some reason the "AND" statement in the SQL "locality.pickup=jobs.pickup AND locality.dropOff=jobs.dropoff" code is acting like an "OR" function... weird

Comment: What does it mean "failed"?

Comment: `$row != mysqli_fetch_assoc($test)` makes no sense whatsoever. And what you actually want here, is also not really clear. Are you trying to determine which records in your table were _not_ selected by your query?

Comment: yes. that's right.

Comment: Then all you need to do is invert the selection criteria. e.g. `WHERE 
NOT (locality.pickup=jobs.pickup AND locality.dropOff=jobs.dropoff)` but I don't know how much sense does this make, since you are using the outdated implicit join

Comment: Do you want to know all the jobs that don't have a matching locality?

Comment: This is too vague, you need to create a concrete ***example***.  Show us some pretend contents of the `jobs` and `locality` tables, and then for that pretend contents show us the result that you want to return.  Read here for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "WHERE NOT" in the SQL but I didn't know you needed to add the brackets. That is why it wasn't behaving correctly

```
SELECT jobs.pickup as myPickup, jobs.dropoff as myDropoff FROM jobs, locality WHERE NOT (locality.pickup=jobs.pickup AND locality.dropOff=jobs.dropoff);
```